# capture json message sent by facebook to bot framework

Tags: facebook, botframework

How can i track the response that was received to bot framework from facebook or any another social network ?

For example , I am sending the location on facebook ( which is not available on framework ) and i am not able to know where it's sent .

Is there any tracker on the bot framework site that can help me do that ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get information about the messages sent to your bot.

1. Create an Azure App Insights instance and register it with the bot framework portal and the Bot Framework will send traces to your bot including exceptions, errors, etc.
2. Run NGROK locally on your machine and point it to your local bot in debug, and you can use the NGROK console to see the rest calls.
3. Inspect the post as it comes into your bot and log the message from the message context.

--jim

Answer (score 1):

The message from facebook, including the location sent by user, is available from:

```
var facebookJson = activity.ChannelData;
```